# Setting up self managed Kubernetes in GCE. Which kind of Persistent Disk to use with a Regional Managed Instance Group?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to set up a k8s cluster using a Regional Managed Instance Group that will create a group of VMs across all the zones of a region. I'm quite a bit confused on how Persistent Disks will work with this set up. I've set up a storage class with the underlying gcePersistentDisk as the provisioner.

If a pod makes a PVC claim to a disk and has replicas across multiple zones in the region, does that mean the PVC cannot be shared by the replicas across zones? Or is there a different way to set up the disk?

Is the only other option to use Zonal MiGs instead? Which will allow me to use PVCs across replicas since they are all guaranteed to be in the same zone

Comment: You can use regional disks as well but it has a limitation to work in 2 node zones only.

Comment: Hello. Do I understand correctly that you are **not** using `GKE` and you are trying to create a self managed cluster with GCE? Is there any particular reason that you want to pursue this solution instead of using `GKE`? Could you tell how did you create your `storageClass`? Please take a look on this example of using Regional Persistent Disks: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-kubernetes-engine-to-deploy-apps-with-regional-persistent-disks .